# Can I insert an aggregation state in an AggregatingMergeTree without going through a materialized view

Tags: clickhouse

I have been using the AggregatingMergeTree for a while by populating them through a materialized view that generates aggregation states from a raw data table. This works great.

I wonder if there is a way to generate aggregation states from arrays I receive without going through table that contains one row per data point.
Example:

I found out I can generate an aggregation state from an array this way:

```
SELECT countState([1,2,3,4,5])
SELECT uniqState(['user1', 'user2', 'user3'])
# Does not work with quantiles
```

Though I did not manage to insert those directly into an aggregating merge tree.
Example:

```
CREATE TABLE state_test_agg(
    id UInt64,
    count_state AggregateFunction(count, UInt32),
    uniq_state AggregateFunction(uniq, String)
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
ORDER BY (id)

INSERT INTO state_test_agg (id, count_state, uniq_state) 
VALUES (1, countState([1,2,3,4]), uniqState(['a', 'b', 'b']))


Code: 184. DB::Exception: Aggregate function countState([1, 2, 3, 4]) is found in wrong place in query
```

If instead I store first the buckets (the arrays) in a table and try to move them into the aggregating merge tree I get

```
CREATE TABLE state_test_raw(
    id UInt64,
    count_bucket Array(UInt64),
    uniq_bucket Array(String)
)
ENGINE MergeTree
ORDER BY id

INSERT INTO state_test_raw (
    id, 
    count_bucket, 
    uniq_bucket)
VALUES
(1, [1,2,3,4,5,5], ['a', 'b', 'c'])

-- so far so good

INSERT INTO state_test_agg 
VALUES (id, count_state, uniq_state) 
SELECT 
    id, 
    countState(count_bucket) as count_state,  
    uniqState(uniq_bucket) as uniq_state 
FROM state_test_raw
GROUP BY id

Code: 47. DB::Exception: Missing columns: 'id' while processing query: 'id', required columns: 'id', source columns: '_dummy'
```

Which is not clear, though I would expect this to be a problem as Clickhouse cannot know if the id column is unique.

Is there a way insert aggregation states generated from arrays and not through a materialized view?

Scenario:
I would like to record metrics and to build rollup tables on them. the simple way would be to have each data point stored as a row in a MergeTree and then to create a materialized view that generates the rollup by populating an aggregating merge tree.
Example:

```
timestamp, response_time, 200
timestamp2, response_time, 205
...
```

Though these data points are already bucketed at the source (thus the arrays).

```
time_bucket_1, response_time, [200, 205]
```

I could expand them and write one row per data point, but it seems I could save storage and bandwidth to Clickhouse, and probably memory used by the materialization step by skipping that step and trying to generate the aggregation state directly from the bucket

Thanks.
Filippo

Comment: https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/input/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [arrayReduce](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-functions/#arrayreduce) to convert an array of items to aggregation state:

```sql
WITH
    arrayReduce('countState', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) AS state_1,
    arrayReduce('uniqState', ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user1']) AS state_2
SELECT
    countMerge(state_1) AS merge_1,
    uniqMerge(state_2) AS merge_2

/*
┌─merge_1─┬─merge_2─┐
│       5 │       3 │
└─────────┴─────────┘
*/
```

---

```sql
INSERT INTO state_test_agg (id, count_state, uniq_state)　
VALUES 
  (1, 
   arrayReduce('countState', [toUInt32(1),2,3,4]), 
   arrayReduce('uniqState', ['a', 'b', 'b'])),
  (1, 
   arrayReduce('countState', [toUInt32(5),5]), 
   arrayReduce('uniqState', ['a', 'b', 'b','c']));
```

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    countMerge(count_state) AS c,
    uniqMerge(uniq_state) AS u
FROM state_test_agg
GROUP BY id

/*
┌─id─┬─c─┬─u─┐
│  1 │ 6 │ 3 │
└────┴───┴───┘
*/
```